# why does my app crash when I call for objectForInfoDictionaryKey: CFBundleShortVersionString

Tags: ios, version, cfbundledocumenttypes

I am trying to get my version number of my app using:

```
NSString * version = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey: @"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
```

but it crashes with this error:

```
[NSString stringWithUTF8String:]: NULL cString
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Check your info.plist to make sure short version (CFBundleShortVersionString) or (Bundle versions string, short) is set.

Your code is fine.  But you can also call it this way:

```
NSString * version = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
```